# Bad Substitution when assigning stat command output to a variable

Tags: linux, bash, command-substitution

I have a script which uses find and `chgrp/chmod` to recursively set certain permissions and group on a directory which is specified in `$1`

To extract the group of this target directory, I use

```
mygrp = ${stat -c %G $mydir}
```

But executed under `bash`, this generates an error:

```
${stat -c %G $mydir}: bad substitution
```

Running the command plainly as

```
stat -c %G $mydir
```

Extracts the group correctly, by I can't seem to get it into the `mygrp` variable.

Comment: You don't use curly brackets for command sub, you use `$()`, also no spaces between `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have been doing

```
$(stat -c %G "$mydir")
```

instead of

```
${stat -c %G $mydir}
```

You should put `$mydir` in double quotes given that directory name may be non-standard , say they contain newlines. If the line were

```
   $(stat -c %G $mydir)
```

then :

```
$ ./your_script_name "dir
37190290"
```

would fail with :

```
stat: cannot stat `dir': No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat `37190290': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing `${...}` with `$(...)`.

```
mygrp=$(stat -c %G "$mydir")
```

Note that no spaces around the `=` are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The `${ }`does a [variable expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

For [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) you should be using `$()`

```
mygrp=$(stat -c %G $mydir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace ${ } with $( ) and remove spaces around the equals sign.

$() is for command substitution.

```
mygrp=$(stat -c %G $mydir)
```